# copying a directory structure via shell scripts

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a directory structure in my machine as following

```
 bhagwat        durga    Sai Baba    vishnu sahastranam
  bhagwat geeta  hanuman  ramayan audio  shiv      vishnu
```

in this all of the above are directories which have blank spaces in their names.
i.e if you do an `ls -l` you will see following

```
drwx------ 1 deel deel        0 2011-09-12 21:34 bhagwat
drwx------ 1 deel deel     8192 2011-09-09 22:35 bhagwat geeta
drwx------ 1 deel deel     4096 2011-10-07 05:10 durga
drwx------ 1 deel deel        0 2011-10-29 09:23 hanuman
drwx------ 1 deel deel     8192 2011-09-30 22:48 ramayan audio
drwx------ 1 deel deel     4096 2011-09-18 12:16 Sai Baba
drwx------ 1 deel deel     4096 2011-09-26 19:19 shiv
drwx------ 1 deel deel     4096 2011-09-26 19:20 vishnu
drwx------ 1 deel deel     4096 2011-09-16 11:35 vishnu sahastranam
```

which has further sub folders in it.I DO NOT want to copy the files or directories.
I want to create a directory structure as above on some other location or device.Which is analogous to what exist on source directory.
Hence I am writing a script for the same as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls /media/New\ Volume/bhajans`;do
echo $i 
done
```

Now the problem with this approach is it results in following output

```
bhagwat
bhagwat
geeta
durga
hanuman
ramayan
audio
Sai
Baba
shiv
vishnu
vishnu
sahastranam
```

if you notice the output the blank space in a directory name are treated as separate directory.Which is not correct.So how can I get rid of this problem.I want to create same directory structure as present on source folder.

**EDIT**
I am using Ubuntu 11.04
**UPDATE**
Each of the sub directory which was cloned has a script named script.sh so not only I am cloning the directory structure.I am also copying the script.sh from parent directories to the cloned destinations.
Kevin and Jonathan thanks for your explanations and answers.

Comment: Did you try quoting your variable?

Comment: @JaypalSingh where exactly do you want the variable to be quoted.

Comment: In your `for loop` try with `echo "$i"`

Comment: @JaypalSingh even after adding the $i over there the spaces are creating problem.

Comment: You will have to change `for` too, do something like `for i in ls /media/New\ Volume/bhajans*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clone the directory structure (recursively) from `olddir` to `newdir`:

```
find olddir -type d -printf "newdir/%P\0" | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

If you want only the first level, add `-maxdepth 1` to the `find`.

Explanation:

`find`, of course, recursively searches a directory and acts on the files it finds. `olddir` tells it to search in the directory named "olddir." `-type d` specifies that it should only act on directories. `-printf` tells it to print the pattern that follows: `newdir` is the directory into which you want to clone the structure. `%P` prints the file name without the `olddir` part, and `\0` tells it to finish the name with a null character. This null character will allow us to pass any legal file name to `xargs`.  `xargs` executes the command you give it using what it reads from stdin as arguments.  `-0` tells it to use the null byte (`\0`) to determine where the arguments (file names, in our case) should be separated.  Otherwise it would use white space, and we know we don't want it to do that. `-p` tells `mkdir` to make the parent directories if they don't already exist.

OK, copying each file over is a bit trickier, but I'm pretty sure this will work in all cases (all  cases where a compatible [gnu] find is installed, at least) after you have cloned the structure with the command above:

```
$ find olddir -name script.sh -printf "%p\0" -printf "newdir/%P\0" | xargs -0L2 cp -n
```

The first `printf` prints the source (existing) file (`%p`), the second prints the destination file. Both end in `\0` as we did earlier. The new argument to `xargs`, `-L2` tells `xargs` to take two (2) arguments (files) at a time from its input and make each command run with just the two of them.  So the order of the `printf` statements and the `L2` are quite important. The `-n` tells `cp` not to overwrite the destination if it exists, just in case one of us made a mistake.

Comment: Using facilities from GNU `find` and `xargs`.  Not bad; but should be documented when no O/S is specified.

Comment: @Kevin I ran it `find /media/New\ Volume/bhajans  -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -0 mkdir -p` this did not gave any error but there was no output also.

Comment: @RegisteredUser You need to include the `-printf` part.

Comment: @Kevin I checked the man page of find for the printf part but I am not clear why exactly it is included and %P\0 what does it do does newdir refer to destination directory.

Comment: @Kevin yes this did worked the way you said but let me know the printf part as why is that important.

Comment: @RegisteredUser The `printf` tells `find` how it should write the directory names.  I've added an explanation.

Comment: @Kevin yes this is great.Your explanation is nice.I am tackling a slightly different issue here.All the sub directories after I cloned have a file script.sh I want to copy just this script in resulting clone.The script.sh name is same in parent but inside it does different job.Let me know your insights about this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs to be: `cd /otherdir; find . -type d -printf ... | xargs -0 mkdir -p` to avoid getting all the path leading to `/otherdir` built under `.`.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I've updated with the command that should copy everything over and a bit more explanation for it.

Comment: It does?  OK, time for me to read the perishing manual page thoroughly, I guess.  Or, at least, schedule a reading before I critique people on it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no it does not do the required thing you are right the error I get is `cp: cannot create regular file `./desired directory/script.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is clone the directory structure and in each of source directory there is a file script.sh this file I need in all the cloned sub directories.

Comment: @Kevin ok I got it first run command 1 and then command 2 does the required job.Thanks for this great attempt you saved my day :)

Comment: @RegisteredUser did you clone the structure first and then use the copy command?

Comment: @Kevin yes I first cloned the structure by the first command and then executed the second command that you explained.That worked.This is just out of curiosity can't these two steps be combined to one?

Comment: @Kevin here is a small problem I noticed.I wanted to execute step 1 to copy files on source to some other device 
the command executed was 
`find /media/source directory/ -type d -printf "/media/destination/%P\0" | xargs -0 mkdir -p`
it copied many directories but for a few it gave error as follows
` mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/destination/some directory with blank ': Invalid argument`
The depth of sub directories for each sub directory are variable and script.sh exist in each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I X mkdir '/new/directory/X'
```

Sorry for the initial mistake.

Comment: it gives me following error `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/New': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `Volume/bhajans/': No such file or directory
`

Comment: On Linux or other systems with GNU `find` and `xargs`, you can/should use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to prevent `xargs` splitting the names on spaces.  You also probably need: `find ... -print0 | (cd /SomeWhere/Else; xargs -0 mkdir)`.

Comment: I ran 
` find /media/New\ Volume/bhajans/ -type d -maxdepth 1 | xargs -I X mkdir ./X
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

mkdir: cannot create directory `.//media/New Volume/bhajans/': No such file or directory
` It repeated many such lines

Comment: I changed the order - see above.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
while IFS=$\n read -r i; do 
    echo "$i"; 
done < <(ls -1 /media/New\ Volume/bhajans)
```

Comment: ./copy.sh: line 4: $(ls /media/New\ Volume/bhajans): ambiguous redirect

Comment: Sure, `read` is a shell built-in and we are using it with an option `-r` which means `raw input. This disables the interpretation of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data`. Second part is comprising of two things. `<` is a simple `input redirection` but `<()` is `process substitution`. This sends data to our `while loop` as if it was coming in from a file.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a shell script, it is a bit messy.  If it can be a script run from the shell, then Perl or Python might serve your purposes better.

### Answer Pair 2

These answers create the directories found in some remote directory in the current working directory.  This is what the question asks for.

#### Shell

Assuming GNU `find` and `xargs`; POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not support `-print0` or `-printf`, nor does POSIX [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) support `-0`.

```
(cd "/media/New\ Volume/bhajans"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0) |
     xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

This ensures that the names listed by `find` are as simple as possible (`./name1`, etc), but the output includes `.` and `mkdir .` fails because the directory exists.  Using `mkdir -p` stops that being an error.

Note that `-print0` is quite different from `-print 0`.  The former is a special command, a variant of the `-print` command to `find`.  Instead of terminating the name with a space or a newline, it terminates it with an ASCII NUL.  This is a clever extension by GNU.  There are only two characters out of 256 possibilities that cannot appear in a file name in a directory.  One of those is `/` because it is used as a path separator; the other is ASCII NUL.  By terminating the names with ASCII NUL (called `'\0'` in C code; it has the byte value zero), the names are unambiguously separated from each other.  It does, however, require programs that expect this convention to work; `xargs` had to be modified to recognize it, for example.

When you wrote `-print 0`, you told `find` to print the names, and then added another directory (called `0`) to the list it was supposed to search, and it objected to that.

When you wrote `-printf 0`, you told find to print a single `0` each time it found a file, so it did.  It didn't add newlines or spaces (you didn't ask it to), so `xargs` saw a line containing `00000000` and then created that as a sub-directory, exactly as you asked it to.

#### Perl

This becomes, if anything, slightly easier:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $otherdir = $ARGV[0];

die "$otherdir is not a directory" unless -d $otherdir;

opendir(my $dir, $otherdir) or die "failed to open directory $otherdir";
while (my $name = readdir($dir))
{
    next if $name eq "." || $name eq "..";
    mkdir $name if (-d $file);
}
closedir($dir);
```

This simply reads the names from the remote directory and creates those directories under the current directory.

### Answer Pair 1

These answers create the directories found in the current working directory in some remote directory.  This is the reverse of the question (but is the way I'd do things automatically).

#### Shell

Assuming GNU `find` and `xargs`; POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not support `-print0` or `-printf`, nor does POSIX [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) support `-0`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
    (cd /SomeWhere/Else; xargs -0 mkdir)
```

#### Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $otherdir = $ARGV[0];

die "$otherdir is not a directory" unless -d $otherdir;

opendir(my $dir, ".") or die "failed to open current directory";
while (my $name = readdir($dir))
{
    mkdir "$otherdir/$name" if (-d $file);
}
closedir($dir);
```

Not formally tested.

Comment: I am not clear on cd /SomeWhere/Else part why is that included there.

Comment: I ran following `find /media/New\ Volume/bhajans  -maxdepth 1 -type d -print 0 | (cd ./ ;xargs -0 mkdir)
find: paths must precede expression: 0
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
`

Comment: I was assuming you did not want to create the directories where they already exist but wanted to create them somewhere else, hence my chosen name `/SomeWhere/Else`.  You wouldn't want to try creating the directories again in the current directory.  Which system are you running on?  Oh, you say Ubuntu...  **Your mistake** `-print0` is different from `-print 0` by a space.

Comment: I see that you are dealing with creating the directories found in a remote directory in the local (current) directory; I am dealing with the files found in the local directory and creating them in a remote directory.  I'll fix my answer to switch roles.

Comment: your assumption is correct.While working on shell I am in destination directory.The I ran the first part of your `find /media/New\ Volume/bhajans/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  -printf 0 | xargs -0 mkdir `
It did worked the way desired. But there was a directory with zero's in it `0000000000`

Comment: let me also know why print 0 is different from print0

Comment: Yes this is great explanation for 0000000s part if you can give me some link which you feel I should have read or any kind of tutorial which will help me.That will be great.Specially for the explanation you gave.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6682/discussion-between-registered-user-and-jonathan-leffler)

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the problem is clearly that bash is treating the spaces in the directory names as a delimiter, and iterating over each word separately. The "right" solution would be to tell it not to do that, but in the absence of that, here's a silly workaround!

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -F | grep "/$" | sed s/\ /###/g`;do
    echo $i | sed s/"###"/\ /g
done
```

First of all, the `ls -F | grep "/$"` part filters your ls results to only return directories and not files (or symlinks). Then, the sed command translates the spaces in your directory names into a placeholder string ("###"), which bash no longer mistakes for a delimiter. Inside the loop, the reverse sed command translates them back into space characters.

Of course, you can replace "###" with any non-whitespace character(s) you want.

Now, to use that to create the directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -F | grep "/$" | sed s/\ /###/g`;do
    tempname=`echo $i | sed s/"###"/\ /g`
    mkdir "otherlocation/$tempname"
done
```

Just replace "otherlocation" with the path you want to use for the new directories.

Comment: I ran following version #!/bin/bash
`for i in `ls /media/New\ Volume/bhajans| sed s/\ /###/g`;do
    tempname=`echo $i | sed s/"###"/\ /g`
    mkdir "./$tempname"
done` It did cloned the directory structure but also copied the files at level one considering them as directories.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry I didn't account for that in the first place. To prevent that, just make the initial ls command only return directories. You can do that by adding the -F option (adds an explicit slash to the end of directory names) and then piping it through `grep "/$"` to select only results that end with a slash. I've edited the code in my original answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ls /media/New\ Volume/bhajans/* ;do
echo $i 
done
```